# Python.ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, graphlab

I am learning how to use Graphlab for machine learning. So, I have this dataset with four columns - There is a column 'name' and another 'review'.

Now, I want to get the review of specific product by the name of the product. So, this is what I tried but I keep the error - ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

```
if (products['name'] == "Vulli Sophie the Giraffe Teether"):
    print (products['review'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8607777f5c3b> in <module>()
----> 1 if (products['name'] == "Vulli Sophie the Giraffe Teether"):
      2     print products['review']

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sarray.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    752         """
    753         # message copied from Numpy
--> 754         raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()")
    755 
    756     def __bool__(self):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Edit -

```
  if (products['name'] == "Vulli Sophie the Giraffe Teether"):
        print products['name']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-1be157eebb1a> in <module>()
----> 1 if (products['name'] == "Vulli Sophie the Giraffe Teether"):
      2     print products['name']

C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sarray.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    752         """
    753         # message copied from Numpy
--> 754         raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()")
    755 
    756     def __bool__(self):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: try : if (products['name'] == "Vulli Sophie the Giraffe Teether"):

Comment: @MohamedALANI:- Thanks. Still getting the same error.

Comment: print `products['name']` and show us.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: - I have uploaded the results. Thank You.

Comment: You may need to do it for each element of your list "products", here it seems you are comparing a list (or a Series) of strings to a String.

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

The error message is letting you know that `products['name']` is a list, therefore you cannot use a straightforward comparator.

If you want to check that any value of the `products['name']` is equal to your 
title, you should change the condition to be:

```
if "Vulli Sophie the Giraffe Teether" in products['name']:
    # other stuff
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

All I know of *Graphlab* is that it *seems* to use the `numpy` module to provide arrays... that said lets start with some data similar to yours

```
In [21]: import numpy as np

In [22]: prods = np.array((['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3])) 

In [23]: prods
Out[23]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['1', '2', '3']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

we have a vector of names ('a', 'b', 'c') and review scores (`1`, `2`, `3`).

Next, to find the positions of a particular name you use a *vectorized boolean expression* like this

```
In [24]: prods[0] == 'b'
Out[24]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

as you can see, the result is a vector of boolean values.

The beauty of `numpy` is that you can address the vectors in fancy modes

```
In [26]: prods[1, prods[0] == 'b']
Out[26]: 
array(['2'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

What I've written is, in `prods` select as the first index `1` (the review scores) and as the second index scan the vector of booleans and use only the `True` items.

What happens if you have no match? nothing

```
In [27]: prods[1, prods[0] == 'd']
Out[27]: 
array([], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

This particular value is `False` so you can use it like this (untested)

```
for my_name in names:
    my_review = products['review', products['name'] == my_name]
    if my_rev:
        do_stuff(my_review)
```